# Calculate disk capacity with given information of disk blocks

Tags: memory, memory-management, filesystems

I got stuck with the follow question regarding file system

```
Consider a file system that uses inodes to represent files. Disk blocks are 4 KB in size, and a pointer to a disk block requires 4 bytes. This file system has 12 direct disk blocks, as well as single, double, and triple indirect disk blocks.

(1). What is the maximum size of a file that can be stored in this file system?
(2). What is the disk capacity?
```

Part 1 is simple, which is

```
(12*4KB)+(1024*4KB)+(1024*1024*4KB)+(1024*1024*1024*4KB) = 4TB
```

as each block has 4KB / 4 bytes = 1024 pointers

But I got stuck at part 2, my initial thought is that since the maximum size of a file that can be stored in the file system is 4TB, the disk capacity is 4TB as well. Is that the case?

Hope anyone can help with my problem. Thank you very much.